# How to make a particular option selected in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have written html as

```
<select class="ddl">
<option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="2">Banana</option>
<option value="3">Cherry</option>
</select>
```

Now I want that if option is 1 then it should be selected as

```
<option value="1" selected="selected">Apple</option>
```

Please help me !!!

Comment: Use `$('select.ddl').val(1)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `val()` method to set the selected option in a `select`, much as you would use it to set the `value` attribute of a standard `input` element. Try this:

```
$('select.ddl').val('1');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".ddl [value=1]").prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: The closing double quote of selector is missing

Comment: Just added space in order to make the selector as a descendant selector

Answer (score 0):

For versions `1.6` and `higher` you can use,

```
$('.ddl option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
```

For `older` versions you can use,

```
$('.ddl option:eq(1)').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').val(1); //To select Apple
```