# set selected value of a select input to another selects option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set selected value of a select input to another selects option value.
when i select a value from first select box, then i want to put that value in to another select box value. but i cant get this value in another select box. i have tried this

**html**

```
<body>
    <select>
        <option id="output"></option>
    </select>

    <select id="sel">
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option>amr</option>
        <option>tomar</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#sel" ).change(function() {
        var ww = $( "#sel" ).val();
        alert(ww);
        $( "#output" ).val(ww);
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ygw9gmp/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [set select option 'selected', by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about trying

```
$( "#output" ).text(ww);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

HTML

```
<body>
<select>
<option id="output"></option>
</select>

<select id="sel">
<option>--select--</option>
<option>amr</option>
<option>tomar</option>
</select>
</body>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#sel" ).change(function() {

var ww = $( "#sel" ).val();
                alert(ww);
        $( "#output" ).text(ww);
});
});
```

For  reference **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vengatesh/1ofvzapc/)**

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to set an ID on an `option` element. Set the ID on the parent instead and use the following to set both the `value` and `text` properties of the `option` element. The `text` is what is visible while `value` is what is submitted to the server when a form is submitted.

```
$( "#output option:first" ).val(ww).text(ww);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#sel" ).change(function() {
        var ww = $( "#sel" ).val();
        //alert(ww);
        $( "#output option:first" ).val(ww).text(ww);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="output">
        <option></option>
    </select>

    <select id="sel">
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option>amr</option>
        <option>tomar</option>
    </select>
```