# How to set the default value of dropdown-menu base on URL param?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a URL with url param `userId`

`http://localhost:8080/assignment?userId=s-00589`

I have a dropdown-menu

I can access the url param and get that userId.

Now I'm wondering how do I use that userId to set my default dropdown-menu to that one.The one with the value="s-00589"

Any helps / suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: [query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) and [select set value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value)

Comment: @charlietfl:  Please do not mark my question as duplicate. I'm not asking how to grab the url params. I'm asking how would I use that to the default value to my dropdown-menu.

Comment: Read my links above....

Comment: Seem like Ben Fried got it. His answer works perfectly.

Comment: Which is what the link above does....Do some research.

Comment: I did. Thanks for link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should literally be as simple as:

```
$('#rn-dd').val(userId_from_url);
```

Comment: Hey man, at least you got my point. The reward will be your man.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help :)

Comment: Will accept your answer as soon as I can.