# Set value of a select HTML element reactively with Meteor

Tags: meteor, html-select, reactive-programming

I want to set the value of an HTML `<select>` element reactively, without changing the various options for the element. I have found a solution, but it in not elegant.

To test, create a barebones Meteor app with `create meteor select` and change the contents of the select.html and select.js files to the following:

select.html

```
<body>
  {{> select}}
</body>

<template name="select">
  <label for="select">{{category}}</label>

  <select id="select">
    <option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Select...</option>
    <option value="Animal">Animal</option> 
    <option value="Vegetable">Vegetable</option>
    <option value="Mineral">Mineral</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

select.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Session.set("category", "")
  Session.set("label", "Category")

  Template.select.onRendered(function () {
    setSelectValue()
  })

  Template.select.helpers({
    category: function () {
      setSelectValue()
      return Session.get("label")
    }
  });

  function setSelectValue() {
    var select = $("#select")[0]
    if (select) {
      select.value = Session.get("category")
    }
  }
}
```

Now launch your app. In the browser console, you can change the value of the `category` Session variable:

```
Session.set("category", "Animal")
```

However, the select element will not update until you change the label:

```
Session.set("label", "category") // was "Category'
```

Now the select element updates, and any subsequent change the `category` Session variable will also update the select element.

```
Session.set("category", "Vegetable") // Now the select element updates
```

Is it possible to achieve the same effect directly, without using this clumsy workaround?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. You can do it as follows:

```
  <select id="select">
    <option value="Animal" {{animalSelected}}>Animal</option> 
    <option value="Vegetable" {{vegetableSelected}}>Vegetable</option>
    <option value="Mineral" {{mineralSelected}}>Mineral</option>
  </select>
```

And helpers that looks something like this:

```
  Template.select.helpers({
    animalSelected: function () {
      return (someCondition === true) ? 'selected' : '';
    },
    vegetableSelected: function () {
      return (someOtherCondition) ? 'selected' : '';
    }
  });
```

A better way might be something like this though:

```
  <select id="select">
    {{#each options}}
      <option value="{{value}}" {{selected}}>{{label}}</option> 
    {{/each}}
  </select>
```

And then you can use `this` in the helpers to decide what is selected and what isn't.

Another option is just using standard jQuery to change the select box. Something like this:

```
$('[name=options]').val( 3 );
```

Or [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the selection set dynamically I usually use a handlebar helper like this

```
Template.newtask.helpers({
  filler: function(element){
    return Session.get(element);
  }
});
```

then in html

```
<select class="browser-default" id="selectedService" name="jobtype">
  <option id="zero" value="{{filler 'type'}}">{{filler 'type'}}</option>
```