# Default value not set for select drop down using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am adding options to the html select dynamically using jQuery at the same time I am setting the default value, but the default value is not shown.

Here is the bare html code initially.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <select id="f_id" class="form-control">
        </select> 
</div>
```

and jQuery code where I am adding the options dynamically

```
var $fTypeSelect = $('#f_id');
$.each(fVal, function(idx, obj){ 
        $fTypeSelect
        .append($("<option></option>").attr("value",obj["ftype_id"]).text(obj["fType"]));
});
```

So far it has added the options to drop down and it works.

I tried to set the default value in the following ways, none of them is showing as selected.

```
$fTypeSelect.val(fTypeDefaultVal);//Not shown as the default value
$fTypeSelect.val(fTypeDefaultVal).change();// Not shown as default value
$fTypeSelect.trigger("chosen:updated");//Default value is still not shown
```

My drop down in the UI is as shown below.
[image]

When drop down is expanded all the options are found. How to set the default value? My jQuery version is 2.1.4.

Comment: `$('#f_id option[value=' + fTypeDefaultVal + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');` try

Comment: `$fTypeSelect.val(fTypeDefaultVal);` should work. Just check if there is an item with `value` equal to `fTypeDefaultVal`

Comment: There is no such item whose value equal to fTypeDefaultVal. But hardcoding the existing value to test also doesn't work.
$fTypeSelect.val("1");

Comment: what about duplicate id for select?

Comment: There is no duplicate id.

Comment: Setting through val() function is working. See this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:1986619?p=preview. Refer this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value for more info

Comment: Messed up with my code, it is working val(). And all the help in comments are correct too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the code I was setting the value for the select dropdown which doesn't exist, hence the issue.

Example:

```
<select id="f_id" class="form-control">
  <option value="1">example1</option>
</select>
```

jQuery snippet

```
var $fTypeSelect = $('#f_id');
$fTypeSelect.val("1");// This is working
// After few lines of messy code I was setting the wrong value as in below
$fTypeSelect.val("string");// This is where I was wrong
```

Because of this it is not showing the option selected.