# Jquery - how to remove selected on other select

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove other checked box every click on my modal
this is my html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sel1">Select role:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="role" name="role">
        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
        <option value="user">User</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

on my javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '.changeRole', function(){
    var role = "admin" or "user"; //just change test, just nvm of this
    $("#role option[value='"+role+"']").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

cause when I execute two times on it will become like this 2 selected and make error on display

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sel1">Select role:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="role" name="role">
        <option value="admin" selected="selected">Admin</option>
        <option value="user" selected="selected">User</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear all first

```
$(document).on('click', '.changeRole', function(){
    var role = "admin" or "user"; 

    //clear all first
    $("#role option").removeAttr("selected");

    $("#role option[value='"+role+"']").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```