# How can I select an option in an html select where I know the value?

Tags: jquery, html-select

In jQuery, if I have an html select with an id of "parentId", how can I select an option where I know the option's value?

Here is the code that I have:

```
function selectParentId(parentId)
{
    $('#parentId').find('option').each(function(index,element){
     if(element.value == parentId)
        element.prop('selected', true);
     });
}
```

How do I need to change the above code?

Comment: Duplicate -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select an item using value you may try this:

```
$('#parentId option[value="yourvalue"]').prop("selected", 1);
```

So your function could be re-written as:

```
function selectDropdown(id, value)
{
    $('#'+id+' option[value="'+value+'"]').prop("selected", 1);
}
```

So you can call it like:

```
selectDropdown('theIdOfSelect', 'theValueOfSelect');
```

An Example [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/174qp30p/5/).

Comment: You beat me to it. But here is a fiddle with something pretty similar: https://jsfiddle.net/174qp30p/4/

Comment: I've updated the fiddle @WheretheresaWill anf mine is more dynamic which can select any `select` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function selectParentId(id,value) {
    $('#' + id).val(value)
}
```