# extracting text from html elements with cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

Using cheerio, `$` is defined as cheerio object, I am trying to get the text from some elements which have a class `forceWordWrap` in a html. The following cheerio selectors are returning nothing. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```js
    const text = $("td[class='forceWordWrap']");
    const date = text.eq(0).text();
    const title = text.eq(1).text();
    const description = text.eq(2).text();
```

```html
     <p/>
      <form name="his" method="post" action="/a/b.axp">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="accept"/>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
        <tr class="rowHeading"> 
          <td width="14%"> 
            <div align="left" style="white-space:nowrap">
                going home
            </div>
          </td>
          <td width="86%"> 
            <div align="left">
                say bye.
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>



            <tr class="rowLight">
              <td  class="boldBodyText forceWordWrap">
                <input type="hidden" name="king" value="Tut"/>
                the kings
              </td>
              <td  class="boldBodyText forceWordWrap">
                    Reminder – Please see the king.
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rowLight">
              <td style="white-space:normal">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="bodyText forceWordWrap">



                    YOu got to do this.


              </td>
            </tr>


      </table>
```

Comment: May be you need to show us your markup..

Comment: Is `$` defined as Cheerio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `$("td.forceWordWrap");` selector as [`Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value **exactly equal to a certain value.**

```js
const text = $("td.forceWordWrap");
const date = text.eq(0).text();
const title = text.eq(1).text();
const description = text.eq(2).text();
console.log(date);
console.log(title);
console.log(description);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="his" method="post" action="/a/b.axp">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="accept" />
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr class="rowHeading">
      <td width="14%">
        <div align="left" style="white-space:nowrap">
          going home
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="86%">
        <div align="left">
          say bye.
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowLight">
      <td class="boldBodyText forceWordWrap">
        <input type="hidden" name="king" value="Tut" />the kings
      </td>
      <td class="boldBodyText forceWordWrap">
        Reminder – Please see the king.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowLight">
      <td style="white-space:normal">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="bodyText forceWordWrap">YOu got to do this.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```