# Cannot select option with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I'm trying to select an option of a Dropdownlist using Javascript. My html Looks like the following:

```
<select id="active-drop" name="active">
    <option value="true">Aktiv</option>
    <option value="false"> Inaktiv </option> 
</select>
```

and my Javascript look like this:

```
$("#active-drop option[value='true']").attr("selected",true);
$("#active-drop option[value='false']").attr("selected",false);
```

The Problem here is, the Attribute is set just fine but the UI isn'z updated accordingly.

btw I already tried using `selectedIndex` but this yielded the same result(the data is set correctly but the UI isn't updated)

Comment: `.prop("selected", true);`

Comment: Doesn't work as well

Comment: Check for duplicate IDs and make sure code is running after page is loaded.

Comment: use $("#active-drop).val("true");

Comment: try attr("selected","selected")

Comment: Same question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value

Comment: Your selector is wrong `console.log($("#active-drop option[value='true']"))` is `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tushar said:

```js
$('#active-drop [value="true"]').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="active-drop" name="active">
    <option value="">Just to prove it</option>
    <option value="true">Aktiv</option>
    <option value="false"> Inaktiv </option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select id="active-drop" name="active">
    <option class="selected" value="true">Aktiv</option>
    <option value="false"> Inaktiv </option> 
</select>
```

And this

```
$(".selected").prop("selected",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one using Jquery:

```js
$('#active').val('ab');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="active" name="active">
  <option value="ab">Aktiv</option>
  <option value="cs">Inaktiv</option>
</select>
```