# How to select a specific option with jQuery without id

Tags: jquery

How can i select a specific option of

```
<div class="col-32">
<select name="DATE" size="1">
<option value="">Select ..</option>
<option value="01/08/2016">01/08/2016</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I want to select the value 01/08/2016

Comment: `$('option[value="01/08/2016"]')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set select option 'selected', by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value)

Comment: Why do you want to select it? To assign the text to a variable? What will you do with it? Color it red? *That will help us know how to help you better.*

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```
$("select[name=DATE]").val("01/08/2016");
```