# retaining selected value in dropdown

Tags: php, jquery

jQuery code: I am unable to retain selected value in the state city dropdowns. When i click on the register now button city field goes blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//script for displaying city on the basis of state
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#state").change(function(){
            var selectedState = $("#state option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/ajax_city.php",
                data: { state : selectedState } 
            }).done(function(data){
                $("#city").html(data)
            });
        });
    });

    // script for displaying states

    $(function(){
        $.get("ajax/ajax_state.php", function(data) {
            $("#state").html(data);
        });
    });
//script for retaining selected values

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#state').val("<?php echo $_POST['state'];?>")
        $('#city').val("<?php echo $_POST['city'];?>");
        $('#expertise').val("<?php echo $_POST['expertise'];?>");
        $('#practice_in').val("<?php echo $_POST['practice_in'];?>");
    });
```

//html for submit button

```
<button md-ink-ripple="" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" id="ad_sign_up" name="ad_sign_up">Register Now!</button>
```

//php code for displaying city: ajax_city.php

```
 <?php
include("../includes/state-array.inc.php");
#include("./includes/state-array.php");
    $state = $_POST["state"];
    // Display city dropdown based on state name
    if($state !== 'Select'){
        foreach($indStateCity[$state] as $value){
            echo "<option>". $value . "</option>";
        }
    } 
     ?>
```

//php code for displaying state: ajax_state.php

```
<?php
include("../includes/state-array.inc.php");
echo "<option selected='selected'>State</option>";
foreach($indStateCity as $key => $value){
            echo "<option>". $key . "</option>";
        }
?>
```

Comment: `$('#state').val("<?php echo $_POST['state'];?>").attr("selected");`

Comment: Show the HTML for the button that you press

Comment: Worth checking: Do the select lists have the same values for `name` as for `id`? It's the `name` that gets posted, but your selectors are on `id` .

Comment: My guess, the button is a type=submit and you are running the AJAX code AND submitting the form. Look at [`event.preventDefault();`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: You also forgot to show the PHP code, so we have no idea what or how you are returning data from that script

Comment: Appears I was right about the button being a `type="submit"`

Comment: Also read this, on how to set the selected option in a dropdown http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have uploaded the html code for button. you can check it out.

Comment: Read my previous comments