# Jquery - highlight selected from select option based from the returned ajax value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax that return values from an another page, I want to target a value that matches from the value ajax returns and select it on the  tag.

Here's my code so far:

```
        success: function(data) {
            $("select[name='account_type']").val(data.account_type).prop('selected', true);
        },
```

I want to target this:

```
   <select class="form-control">
          <option value="0">DEBIT</option>
          <option value="1">CREDIT</option>
   </select>
```

So if the ajax call returns value of 1, then CREDIT should be :selected

Comment: Set `name` of `select` element as you are using it i.e. `<select name="account_type" class="form-control">` and remove `.prop('selected', true)`

Comment: oh yeah, darn, I forgot that. haha thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set select option 'selected', by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ajax:

```
success: function(data) {
            $("select[name='account_type']").val(data.account_type).prop('selected', true);
        },
```

For HTML

```
<select name="account_type" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">DEBIT</option>
          <option value="1">CREDIT</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: @Root please mark as accepted if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Set `name` of `select` element as you are using it

```
<select name="account_type" class="form-control">
```

and `.prop()` is *not* required so just remove it.

```js
$("select[name='account_type']").val(1)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="account_type" class="form-control">
  <option value="0">DEBIT</option>
  <option value="1">CREDIT</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

prop is not needed:

```
 success: function(data) {
            $("select[name='account_type']").val(data.account_type);
        },
```

then give name else use `$("select.form-control")`

```
   <select name=account_type class="form-control">
          <option value="0">DEBIT</option>
          <option value="1">CREDIT</option>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML :

```
<select class="form-control" name="account_type">
  <option value="0">DEBIT</option>
  <option value="1">CREDIT</option>
```

Your ajax response function :

```
success: function(data) {
$('select[name="account_type"]').find('option[value=data.account_type]').attr("selected",true);
```

},