# Reset Dropdown Menu to First Option After OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a drop down menu like below:

```
<select onChange="window.open(this.value)">
<option selected="selected" value="">--select an url--</option>
<option value="URL1">URL1</option>
<option value="URL2">URL2</option>
<option value="URL3">URL3</option>
</select>
```

I would like to have the dropdown menu return to "--select an url--" option,
instead of URL option,
everytime after a selection was made.

Can someone show me how to implement the codes? 
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set select option 'selected', by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value)

Comment: I am assuming you are using jquery - Please use the below code to reset it back to the initial selection
$('select').val('initialvalue')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to the `onChange` event:

```
this.value = '';
```

So the code would look like:

```
<select onChange="window.open(this.value);this.value = '';">
  <option selected="selected" value="">--select an url--</option>
  <option value="URL1">URL1</option>
  <option value="URL2">URL2</option>
  <option value="URL3">URL3</option>
</select>
```

This is assuming the '--select an url--' has an empty option value i.e. `value=""`

Comment: Great - can you mark this as the answer so the question is marked as solved?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="dropDownBox">
<option selected="selected" value="">--select an url--</option>
<option value="URL1">URL1</option>
<option value="URL2">URL2</option>
<option value="URL3">URL3</option>
</select>

<script>
$("#dropDownBox").change(function() {
   var test = $(this).val();
   $(this).val("");
   window.open(test);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply. Yes! This will work!