# how to set select value from database in jquery selectize plugin

Tags: jquery, html, spring-boot, drop-down-menu, selectize.js

I'm new to jQuery selectize and I'm having issues in setting the value to a `<select>` from database during editing the form. The `<option>` is hardcoded in HTML.

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="agentType" id="agentType">
    <option value="">--Select Agent Type--</option>
    <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
    <option value="Partner">Partner</option>
</select>
```

Let's say the two values are saved in database viz(Individual & Partner).

[image: database]

And when I hit edit, I want one of **Agent Type** to be pre-selected and other one in the drop-down corresponding to value saved in database. Images shown Shown below:

[image: before][image: After]

Jquery:

```
$('#agentDataTable tbody').on( 'click', '.dataEdit', function () {
    var data = agentDataTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();

    $('#agentForm #agentName').val(data.agentName);
    var $select = $('#agentForm #agentType').selectize();
    var control = $select[0].selectize;
    control.clear();
    control.clearOptions();
    control.addOption({text: data.agentType});
    control.setValue(data.areaPincodeId, true);
    });
```

But nothing shows at all in dropdown.

I've tried many other references but no answer matched my query as everyperson has their own ways.

Comment: Have you tried `$('#agentType').val(data.agentType).selectize()`?

Comment: @User863 yep I tried that too.

Comment: is your HTML is the same as provided here? what does data.agentType contain?

Comment: What is `selectize`? I'm guessing this is sum kind of plugin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set select option 'selected', by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value)

Comment: @Liam yes you're correct it is a plugin

Comment: @User863 I've update the jquery code have a look

Comment: Well what does that plugin say about setting values? This isn't just a select, it's the plugin that controls it

Comment: @Liam [selectize](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md) plugin docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectize` is a plugin on jQuery provided on GitHub as far as I know,

In your question you didn't showed the method where you are making the `select` field selectize and by seeing your query my guess is that you didn't wrote that method properly and you're missing `id: data.agentType` in your datatable's method.

I'm providing you a method to do selectize to `select` field and datatable's query to fetch it.

Replace the below method in your jquery file for selectize.

```
function setAgentTypeSelect() {
    var $agentTypeSelect = $('#agentForm #agentType').selectize({
        selectOnTab: true,
        closeAfterSelect: true,
        persist: true,
        valueField: 'id',
        labelField: 'text',
        options: [],
        preload: true,
        create: false
    }); 
}
```

And in your datatable method just replace your addOptions `control.addOption({id: data.agentType, text: data.agentType});`

I'm sure that by changing these things will get what you wanted to do.