# show select option from database ajax json in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to get data from database and show it to edit form. When I'm using json data, I've got problem on show the data to `select option` field form. It still show `option value id` ascending  , not show `value id selected` from database.

In the example, I need to change `lesson` with `id` number  `7`. And in the `select option`, it shows lesson from `id` number `1`, but when I click the `select option`, it shows `id` with number `7`.

Here's the jquery code

```
function edit(id){

    $.ajax({
        url : url + 'Lesson/find_by_id',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(response){
             var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);

             $('input[name="id"]').val(jsonData.id);
            
             $('select[name="lesson"]').val(jsonData.lesson_id);
             $('textarea[name="description"]').val(jsonData.description);

             
        }
    });

    $('#editModal').modal('show');
}
```

Here's the form code

```
 <select class="form-control select-search" name="lesson" style="width: 100%" required="">
    <?php foreach($lesson as $row): ?>
            <option value="<?=$row->lesson_id?>" > <?=strtoupper($row->name)?> </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Here's the controller code

```
public function find_by_id(){
    $lesson_id = $this->input->post('id');
    $data     = $this->lesson->find_lesson($lesson_id);

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Do you know how to fix the code ?

Thank you

Comment: If you're seeing that behaviour it means that the value of `jsonData.lesson_id` does not match any `value` attribute in an `option` within the target select. We can't offer any more help than that at this point

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan, so why when we click the `select option` arrow, then it shows `value selected` ?

Comment: It is hard to understand your question, but I think you are saying that your Javascript *does* select the right option, but the dropdown is not updated to show that?

Comment: Hi @Don'tPanic, yes it is

Comment: I think you are saying that your Javascript does select the right option, but the dropdown is not updated to show that?.
use this after setting value of dropdown $('.check').trigger('change');

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33252307/6089612

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set select option 'selected', by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value)