# How to automatically select option when page loads using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this filter and I want to automatically select an option when the page loads using jquery.

```
<div class="panel-collapse collapse show" id="filter-location-450e878">
<div class="panel-body">
<select name="list_filter[listing_location]" data-tax="listing_location" data-mode="multi" data-max-items="1" data-metakey="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or" class="form-control javo-selectize-option selectized" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option></select>
<div class="selectize-control form-control javo-selectize-option multi plugin-remove_button"><div class="selectize-input items not-full has-options">
<input type="select-one" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" placeholder="Banana" style="width: 70px;" class=""></div>
<div class="selectize-dropdown multi form-control javo-selectize-option plugin-remove_button" style="display: none; width: 0px; top: 41px; left: 0px;">
<div class="selectize-dropdown-content"></div>
</div></div></div></div>

<div class="selectize-dropdown multi form-control javo-selectize-option plugin-remove_button" style="display: none; width: 225px; top: 41px; left: 0px; visibility: visible;">
<div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
<div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="157">Banana</div>
<div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="276">Orange</div>
</div></div>
```

Can somebody help me coz I don't know what mess I have put myself into.

Comment: you are using already in your code `selected="selected"`, work on `<option>` tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set select option 'selected', by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).read(function () {
//way 1
$("eleDropdown").val(YourValues).select2();
//.select2() if you are using select2 js from dropdown.

//way 2
$("eleDropdown").find("option[value=" + youroptionvalue + "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

**second**

```
$(document).load(function () {
//way 1
$("eleDropdown").val(YourValues).select2();
//.select2() is you are using select2 js from dropdown.

//way 2
$("eleDropdown").find("option[value=" + youroptionvalue + "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

call any of this one on right place on your code.

**This might help you with something**