# Laravel CRUD Ajax Edit: show selected value from table on dropdown

Tags: ajax, laravel, html-select, crud, edit

**Controller:**

```
$school_edit = SchoolData::find($school_id);
```

**Ajax:**

```
$('#edit_school_name').val(response.school_edit.school_name);                      
$('#edit_school_description').val(response.school_edit.school_description);
$('#edit_cat_id').val(response.school_edit.school_id);
$('#edit_subject_name').val(response.school_edit.subject_name);
```

**Form:**

```
<input type="text" id="edit_school_name" class="form-control form-group w-100" placeholder="School Name">
<textarea id="edit_school_description" class="form-control w-100" placeholder="School Description" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
```

my current code outputs school_name and school_description without any issue, but how do I do the same in a dropdown? for instance, the options are "Math" and "Science", in the table data, "Science" is chosen and I need the first option to show in my edit as "Science".

So basically, if "Science" is chosen, it will look something like:

```
  <select id="edit_subject_name">
    <option>(selected subject from database)</option>
    <option>Math</option>
    <option>Science</option>
  </select>
```

normally, in the add form, there are only two options, Math and Science. The edit form will have three, the first option in the edit will always be the selected one from the database.

I know i cannot simply do:

```
<option id="edit_subject_name"></option>
<option>Math</option>
<option>Science</option>
```

Because the option content will be empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the subject has an ID or slug? If not, you can convert the name into a slug, then pass that as the value of option, then you can compare to check what was selected in the dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing https://stackoverflow.com/a/16979926/7970660:

1. Assign a value to your options.

   For Example:

   ```
   <select id="edit_subject_name">
      <option value="Math">Math</option>
      <option value="Science">Science</option>
   </select>
   ```
2. In your AJAX:

   ```
   $("#edit_subject_name").val(response.school_edit.subject_name).change();
   ```

Comment: tried this, any reason why mine returns blank?

Comment: Please show how you have set the option's values. These have to be an identical math for it to set correctly

Comment: I am not sure what to add when you meant show how I set the option's values. I only have two  under select: Math and Science

Comment: You haven't set the value attribute: `value="Math"`

Comment: ah, youre right. that's my bad, thanks for the fix youve been a great help