# I can't select an option using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is my HTML:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Departement</label>
    <select class="form-control departement"
            name="worker_departement_edit"
            id="worker_departement_edit" 
            required >
      <option class="default" disabled selected value="">
         Please select a departement!
      </option>
    </select>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please select an option!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is a event when I click the edit button to append option inside the select:

```
$(".departement").append('<option value="' 
                        + element['id_departement'] 
                        + '">' + element['depart_name'] 
                        + '<option>')
```

And this is my code when I want to select an option:

```js
$("#worker_departement_edit").children(".default-depart").remove()
$("#worker_departement_edit").val(datas[0]["departement"]).change();
```

I was `console.log` this `$("#worker_departement_edit").children(".default-depart")` and it's was fine
also I try to console.log the variable datas and its was fine too

What i've try:

```js
$(".default-depart").remove()
$(".worker_departement_edit")
 .children('option[value=' 
          + datas[0]["departement"] 
          + ']')
 .attr("selected", true)
```

Comment: What is `element` or `datas`?

Comment: `element` is my variable on a function,  
the function is called when i click the edit button, 
i call the function to fill the select, 
the function is `get_departement()`.

`datas` is my variable , 
after i call the `get_departement()`, 
i use ajax to get the a specific data for current data i clicked, 
if ajax success, i parse the return and place it to variable `datas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code mostly works fine.  I've included a a working, simplified version of your code below, click Run to see it in action.

A few things I noticed:

- Your `.append()` code uses `<option> ... <option>` - that last tag should be a *closing* tag, `</option>`;
- There is no element with class `default-depart`, so you can't remove it, and that code is not doing anything (unless that element exists but you have not included it here);
- It would make it much easier for ppl to help if you can create a [*MINIMAL*, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - that means including a small part of your `datas` array, and removing CSS, HTML, etc not related to this specific problem;
- This question is really a duplicate, and should be closed I think, eg: [Set select option 'selected', by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value)

```js
var datas = [
    {id: 1, department: 'Work'},
    {id: 2, department: 'Fun'},
    {id: 3, department: 'Lunch'},
];

var $select = $(".departement"),
    $info = $('#info');

$('#add').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $select.append('<option value="' 
        + datas[2]['id']
        + '">' + datas[2]['department']
        + '</option>');
    $info.append('Option added!<br>');
});

$('#select').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $select.val(datas[2]['id']).change();
    $info.append('Option selected!<br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Departement</label>
<select class="departement" name="worker_departement_edit" id="worker_departement_edit">
    <option class="default" disabled selected value="">Please select a departement!</option>
</select>

<p>
    <button id="add">Add An Option</button>
    <button id="select">Select An Option</button>
</p>

<p id="info"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `prop()`.

Both `attr()` and `prop()` are used to get or set the value of the specified property of an element attribute, but `attr()` returns the default value (Original state) of a property whereas `prop()` returns the current value (Current state).

```
$("#worker_departement_edit").val(datas[0]["departement"])
$("#worker_departement_edit").find('option[value='+datas[0]["departement"]+']').prop("selected", true)
```

Comment: Still not working...

this is the html element when i inspect after i click the edit button and trigger that code

`<select class="form-control departement" name="worker_departement_edit" id="worker_departement_edit" required=""><option class="default default-depart" disabled="" selected="" value="">Please select a departement!</option><option value="1">Animator</option><option value="2">3D Modelling</option></select>`

Comment: Remove `selected value=""` from default option.

Comment: class `default-depart` is not in your html. How do you suppose to remove element using it?

Comment: i cant remove the `selected value=""` because its needed for other element (because it was a global function).
so i used jquery `$("#worker_departement_edit").children(".default-depart").removeAttr("selected").removeAttr("value")` and it worked, but it still cant select the option what i asked before

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check now and one more thing `worker_departement_edit` is id but you are using it as class `$(".worker_departement_edit")
 .children('option[value=' 
          + datas[0]["departement"] 
          + ']')
 .attr("selected", true)`

Comment: oh no, when i inspect the select the `selected value=""` is still there, but if i console.log the element it gone `<option class="default default-depart" disabled="">Please select a departement!</option>`