# How select an option with object value in select box?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select box with options, which its options' value are objects. Like this:

```
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
    <option value="{name: 'A', age: '20'}">A</option>
    <option value="{name: 'B', age: '30'}">A</option>
    <option value="{name: 'C', age: '40'}">A</option>
</select>
```

I need to know when I get an object like this, `{name: 'B', age: '30'}` from api, how can I select the option which has this object as value in HTML?
In this case I want to second option be selected.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  The value is always a string, are you just looking to parse that string as JSON?  Something else?  Perhaps you could show your attempt and indicate specifically what isn't working as expected?

Comment: @David I get the value {name: 'B', age: '30'} from api, and in HTML I want to the option with this value be selected

Comment: If you want to find the option that has this specific string value set, then you can use `querySelector` with an attribute selector, and in combination with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape to make that string valid inside a selector.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/

Comment: @amiria703 your link has simple value, The values on your links are not objects.

Comment: @AtousaDarabi Can you change the `value` field to be valid json? You would have this instead `value="{&quot;name&quot;: &quot;A&quot;, &quot;age&quot;: &quot;20&quot;}"`? In the current state it's a bit difficult to parse the data of the `value` field and compare to what your API returned.

Comment: @AtousaDarabi: The value is *always a string*.  The strings you're using are (almost) JSON (but need to use double-quotes instead of single-quotes).  You can get or set the selected value exactly as you would any other *string* value, it doesn't really matter what characters are contained within that string or what object it may represent when de-serialized.  Again, have you tried anything at all?  What isn't working in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the desired option using a common css selector for those elements having a specified value attribute (as string).

I show you in this demo a function `selectOptionByJSONValue` that accepts a `jsonValue` string and will return the corresponding option. This demo selects the C option when the page is loaded, by finding it using the `input` variable as json value, and setting its `selected` attribute.

In all fairness in case of doing it again on the same `select` element, all options should have the `selected` attribute removed before any one else gets it after.

```js
const input = "{name: 'C', age: '40'}";
const option = selectOptionByJSONValue(input);
option.setAttribute('selected', true);

function selectOptionByJSONValue(jsonValue){
  const optionSelector = `#mySelect option[value="${jsonValue}"]`;
  return document.querySelector(optionSelector);  
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
    <option value="{name: 'A', age: '20'}">A</option>
    <option value="{name: 'B', age: '30'}">B</option>
    <option value="{name: 'C', age: '40'}">C</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: OP mentioned they have an object as an input, not a string. Also, your `input` is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```js
const sel=document.getElementById("mySelect"), btn=document.querySelector("button");

[...sel.options].forEach(o=>{
  if (o.value) o.value=JSONstring(o.value)     // standardize the option values using JSONstring()
})

document.body.onclick=ev=>{ 
 if (ev.target.tagName!=="BUTTON") return
 sel.value=JSONstring(ev.target.textContent);  // find the selection option with the correct value and select it
}

function JSONstring(str){  // converts any "object describing string" into a sorted and valid JSON string - if possible ...
 return JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(eval("("+str+")")).sort(([k1],[k2])=>k1.localeCompare(k2))))
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
    <option value="">Please choose ...</option>
    <option value="{name: 'A', age: '20'}">A</option>
    <option value="{name: 'B', age: '30'}">B</option>
    <option value="{name: 'C', age: '40'}">C</option>
</select>

<button> {name:       'B'  , age:"30"}</button>
<button>{age:"40", name:   'C'} </button>
```

Please note that I am using `eval()` to convert your "object describing string" into a sorted and standardised JSON format. This can then very easily be used to set the select filed accordingly. `eval()` is shunned by many developers as being "unsafe". However, I believe that the associated risk in this use case is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value you selected by change event.
Also, you can set an option by default by "selected" attribute.

```js
const select = document.getElementById('mySelect');

select.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
 console.log(event.target.value)
});
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
    <option value="{name: 'A', age: '20'}">A</option>
    <option value="{name: 'B', age: '30'}" selected>B</option>
    <option value="{name: 'C', age: '40'}">C</option>
</select>
```